# codeigniter access controller variable in config

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm want to do something like this

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| WARNING: You MUST set this value!
|
| If it is not set, then CodeIgniter will try guess the protocol and path
| your installation, but due to security concerns the hostname will be set
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production!
|
| If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
| a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
|
*/
echo $code;
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';
```

Now in my home controller

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller{
public function index(){

$x=1;
if($x==1){
$this->config->set_item('code', 'somevalue1');
}else if($x==2){
$this->config->set_item('code', 'somevalue2');
}
}
}
```

Now how can i access value from home file of Controller to application/config/config.php

Comment: Also your project base_url should be `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Answer (score 0):

**In Config.php**

```
$config['code']=''; # Its better this to define at end of config file
```

**To set value**

```
$this->config->set_item('code', 'My Value');
```

**To Access the value**

```
echo $this->config->item('code');
```

Comment: did you check this ??

Comment: set base url in controller then. Keep mind as i know baseUrl should be static. Cz else you will face HOST injection

Comment: Using $this when not in object context in in config file echo $this->config->item('code'); not working

Comment: `$config['code']='here';` add like this and echo it

Comment: base url is static only. but i want to pass some code with base url that code is dynamic

Comment: `<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>controller.method/your/data" ..`

Comment: can i over right base url function , because im already calling base url function in ever page

Comment: set in session and call it to baseurl.

Comment: may be set baseurl will wroks

Comment: Now i want to add some code with base url ... i don't want to go each and ever file to add that code in ever link